# golang opengl windows installation issues

Tags: windows, opengl, go, glew

I'm trying to install ("go get...") opengl (https://github.com/go-gl/gl) on a Windows7 machine .  I have 32 bit Go installed. 32 bit glew .lib .dll and .h files downloaded. I modified the path environment variable to point to these glew files. I have cygwin along with mingw installed. I also have git and mercurial installed for the use of go get command.  I also have my GOPATH and GOROOT set as appropriate.

```
PS C:\Users\peterpan> go get github.com/go-gl/gl
# github.com/go-gl/gl
In file included from C:\cygwin\home\peterpan\GoProjects\src\github.com\go-gl\gl\attriblocation.go:7:0:
gl.h:2:21: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
#include <GL/glew.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

Now does anyone know where the glew dll and .h files are supposed to go on windows to make compilation work with go get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the location of your MinGW install, there are likely folders called `include`, `lib`, and `bin`. You'll want `glew.h` in `include\GL\glew.h`. If they're not under MinGW they're likely somewhere under your Cygwin install.

However, there's a trick here. Since you say you have a `.lib` file, I'm going to assume you downloaded the precompiled Windows binaries. You can't do this, those are for Visual C and use with Visual Studio. You're, unfortunately, going to have to build it from source. It's a bit finicky, but there should be resources to help you build to a MinGW target.

After you finish building it, you should get the files `glew32.dll` and `libglew32.dll.a`. These correspond to the `.dll` and the `.lib` you mentioned, respectively. You'll want `glew32.dll` in either `bin` or `C:\Windows\System32` (though technically anywhere in your Path should work, those are the more "standard" locations). You'll want the `.a` file in the `lib` directory.

Comment: Can we use the visual C build with go get... Not sure what compiler go get uses by default?

Comment: Ok I was able to successfully get it installed.  First I had to get make,sed,mkdir and other MSYS tools for mingw.  The mingw installer offers these msys tools during setup.  I then used the msys make to compile glew source code. I put the lib and header files in my mingw /lib and /include directories. After all of that, go get successfully took off and compiled. Thank you for the help!